# Como encontrrar uma sequencia ordinaria de keys numa Array?

Tags: php, array, lógica, arraylist

> O objetivo é encontrar a próxima sequência ordinaria de 03 keys dentro de uma
>   array com índices quebrados, no exemplo seria 4,5,6 ou 7,8,9

### CÓDIGO

```
<?php
        $myArray = array(
        'item_1',
        'item_2',
        'item_3',
        'item_4',
        'item_5',
        'item_6',
        'item_7',
        'item_8',
        'item_9',
        'item_10',
        'item_11',
    );

    $arrOriginal = $myArray;

    unset($myArray[2]);
    unset($myArray[3]);

    print_r(PHP_EOL . "Lista índices Quebrados" . PHP_EOL);
    foreach ($myArray as $keyItem => $itemValue) {
        echo 'Key: ' . $keyItem . ', Valor: ' . $itemValue . PHP_EOL;
    }

    print_r(PHP_EOL . "Lista Original" . PHP_EOL);

    foreach ($arrOriginal as $keyItem => $itemValue) {

        echo 'Key: ' . $keyItem . ', Valor: ' . $itemValue . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

### RETURN

```
Lista índices Quebrados

Key: 0, Valor: item_1
Key: 1, Valor: item_2
Key: 4, Valor: item_5
Key: 5, Valor: item_6
Key: 6, Valor: item_7
Key: 7, Valor: item_8
Key: 8, Valor: item_9
Key: 9, Valor: item_10
Key: 10, Valor: item_11

Lista Original

Key: 0, Valor: item_1
Key: 1, Valor: item_2
Key: 2, Valor: item_3
Key: 3, Valor: item_4
Key: 4, Valor: item_5
Key: 5, Valor: item_6
Key: 6, Valor: item_7
Key: 7, Valor: item_8
Key: 8, Valor: item_9
Key: 9, Valor: item_10
Key: 10, Valor: item_11
```

### RESULTADO ESPERADO NESSE EXEMPLO

4,5,6 ou 7,8,9

Comment: Por exemplo se o invés de `unset($myArray[2]);  unset($myArray[3]);` fizesse `unset($myArray[3]);  unset($myArray[7]);` o resultado seria `[0,1,2]`, `[4,5,6]` e , `[8,9,10]`?

Comment: Na verdade o unset é a ação de remover um item no código, mas a ideia é pegar apenas as sequências consecutivas de 3 índices dentro de uma array na qual vai constar índices faltantes como no exemplo.

Comment: Isso que eu quero saber se eu remover aqueles indices específicos, `3` e o `7`, o resultado vai ser `[0,1,2]`, `[4,5,6]` e `[8,9,10]` ou será algo diferente como somente a primeira ocorrência `[0,1,2]`?

Comment: Isso, [0,1,2], [4,5,6] e [8,9,10]

Comment: Estou implementando uma lista de reserva, na qual estou gerando as horas de 30 em 30 minutos, supondo que que a reserva dure 90 minutos consecutivos imagino que tomará 03 indices dentro da array. Por isso quando o usuário for reservar tem que aparecer somente a reserva que inicie no indice que contenha +2 pra frente.

Comment: Entendi, no momento eu estou fechando o escritório(fuso horário do pantanal). Quando chegar em casa lhe dou uma força.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
        $myArray = array(
        'item_1',
        'item_2',
        'item_3',
        'item_4',
        'item_5',
        'item_6',
        'item_7',
        'item_8',
        'item_9',
        'item_10',
        'item_11'
    );


    unset($myArray[2]);
    unset($myArray[3]);

    // Cria um array com as chaves de $myArray
    $chaves = array_keys($myArray); 

    // Inicializa a array que receberá as arrays de chaves consecutivas 
    $consecutivos = [];

    // Pega a quantidade de chaves
    $tamanho = count($chaves);

    // Verifica se há mais de duas chaves
    if($tamanho > 2){
       // Caso haja mais de duas chaves itera por elas menos as duas últimas
       for ($i=0; $i < ($tamanho - 2) ; $i++){
          // Verifica se as 3 chaves, a partir de índice $i, são consecutivas
          if($chaves[$i] === ($chaves[$i+1] - 1) && 
             $chaves[$i] === ($chaves[$i+2] - 2)   ) {
               //Caso sejam consecutivas as coloca no array $consecutivos[]
               $consecutivos[] = [$chaves[$i], $chaves[$i+1] , $chaves[$i+2]];
               //Despreza o dois próximos índices a partir de índice $i
               $i += 2;
          } 
       }  
    }

    print_r( $consecutivos);
```

Que retorna:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

)
```

Link para o código: https://repl.it/repls/SquareFruitfulExponents

Comment: Perfeito, nota 10. Muito Obrigado Augusto Vasques.